# Asymtotic bound of some number theoritic function.

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

I am self-studying asymptotic behavior of some number theoretic function and the following question comes up.

Let $n$ be a natural number having prime factorization $p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$.
Let $\tau:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $\tau(n) = \prod_{i=1}^r(k_i+1)$. Then the literature says that $\forall \epsilon >0 ~\tau(n) = o(n^\epsilon)$ (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3698)).

Now define $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $f(n) = \prod(k_i+1)$ where the product runs over all those $i$ such that $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Then what will be the asymptotic order of $f$? can we have some function $g(n)$ such that $f(n) = O(g(n))$?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Now posted to MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437388/asymptotic-bound-of-some-number-theoretic-function